# Angular UI TimePicker Bi-Directional Behaviour

Tags: angularjs, timepicker, behavior

I would like to know which  parte of the directive source code I should modify in order to implement bi-directional behaviour with this component ?. Because upon certain conditions, I should change the time to "08:00" or leave it like it is... I saw that an isolated scope is implemented so maybe that explains the behavuour...

Thankx

Comment: paste your code please :p

Comment: A code example, or link to the datepicker you are using would be very useful.

Answer (score 2):

The `ng-model` attribute on your timepicker (if it exists), represents the bound data point exposed for you to change, and be changed by this directive.

```
<timepicker ng-model='scopeVariableYouBindToDatePickerToHaveAccessToSelectedValue' />
```

If you have an example of the source code, or the directive itself, please feel free to post an example or link.

Answer (score 1):

Not fully sure I understand, but here goes nothing...

```
  $scope.update = function() {
    var d = new Date();
    d.setHours( 8 );
    d.setMinutes( 0 );
    $scope.mytime = d;
  };
```

OR better if you do not want to have to click a button, but this watch would have to be tied to some event of course:

```
$scope.$watch('something_to_watch', function(new, old) {
        var d = new Date();
        d.setHours( 8 );
        d.setMinutes( 0 );
        $scope.mytime = d;
});
```

And as Sean Larkin said, your html would then look like this:

```
<timepicker ng-model='{{mytime}}' />
```

Comment: Guys... Thankx for answering... Not sure what happened, but it's working... Thankx you so much... I'll will read your answers... For sure I need to buy an angular book to learn more in depth...

Comment: I modifiy the directive source code and put "scope: true" !; at least, that was the change I remembered I did over the js... And it worked ! :D